# having table for fixed data or Enum?

Tags: c#

I have a table that has Constant Value...Is it better that I have this table in my Database(that is SQL)or have an Enum in my code and delete my table?
my table has only 2 Columns and maximum 20 rows that these rows are fixed and get filled once,first time that i run application.

Comment: if my answer helps you, please click on gray 'check' button on the left side of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create an Enum for your case. Since the values are fixed(*and I am assuming that the table is not going to change very often*) you can use Enum. Creating a table in database will require an unnecessary hit to the database and will require a database connection which could be skipped if you are using Enum.

Also a lot may depend on how much operation you are going to do with your values. For example: its tedious to query your Enum values to get distinct values from your table. Whereas if you will use table approach then it would be a simple `select distinct`. So you may have to look into your need and the operations which you will perform on these values.

As far as the performance is concerned you can look at: [Enum Fields VS Varchar VS Int + Joined table: What is Faster?](https://www.percona.com/blog/2008/01/24/enum-fields-vs-varchar-vs-int-joined-table-what-is-faster/)

> As you can see, ENUM and VARCHAR results are almost the same, but join
>   query performance is 30% lower. Also note the times themselves –
>   traversing about same amount of rows full table scan performs about 25
>   times better than accessing rows via index (for the case when data
>   fits in memory!)
>
> So, if you have an application and you need to have some table field
>   with a small set of possible values, I’d still suggest you to use
>   ENUM, but now we can see that performance hit may not be as large as
>   you expect. Though again a lot depends on your data and queries.

Comment: What if he queries using stored procedures based on SQL agent (scheduled)  ? Should he also copy these Enum values and declare them as variables in the procedure or maybe scalar function (centralized) ?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your needs.

You may want to translate the Enum Values (if you are showing it in GUI) and order a set of record based on translated values. For example: imagine you have a Employees table and a Position column. If the record set is big, and you want to sort or order by translated position column, then you have to keep the enum values + translations in database.

Otherwise KISS and have it in code. You will spare time on asking database for values.

Answer (score 0):

I depends on character of that constants.

If they are some low level system constants that never should be change (like pi=3.1415) then it is better to keep them only in code part in some config file. And also if performance is critical parameter and you use them very often (on almost each request) it is better to keep them in code part.

If they are some constants (may be business constants) that can change in future it is Ok to put them in table - then you have more flexibility to change them (for instance from admin panel).

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you actually need.

With Enum

1. It is faster to access
2. Bound to that certain application. (although you can share by making it as reference, but it just does not look as good as using DB)
3. You can use in switch statement
4. Enum usually does not care about value and it is limited to int.

With DB

1. It is slower, because you have to make connection and query.
2. The data can be shared widely.
3. You can set the value to be anything (any type any value).

So, if you will use it only on certain application, Enum is good enough. But if several applications are going to use it, then DB would be better option.